# What is this pink flower with dark green leaves?

Tags: identification

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a [camellia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia) sasanqua, a.k.a. the [Christmas camellia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_Camellia).  I've no experience with it.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, Camellia.  Japonicas bloom in spring and Sasanquas bloom in the late fall.  They are very common here in the Piedmont of NC.